# Accessing JSP objects from using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a JSP file that has both my JSP code and Javascript code, the JSP basically has this huge arrayList having land coordinates that I need to draw on a google map object using Javascript since google currently has no version of google maps that support JSP natively, here is my code:

```
        <%
        List<LandCoordinates> annex = new LandCordinatesDAO().getLandCoordinates();
                    for (LandCoordinates an : annex) {
                        out.print(an.getX());
                        out.print(an.getY());
                    }
       %>


 <script>


function drawLandMarkCenter(x, y)
 {
var plotCenter = {lat: x, lng: y};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 18,
center: plotCenter,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
});

return map;
```

}

How Can I access elements in `List<LandCoordinates> annex` from my javascript code?

Comment: You cannot. Only values you can access.

Comment: If you give output the values into a hidden html element with unique ids then you will be able to access them from JS

Comment: could u please give me a sample, I am very new to JSP and having serious issues getting a hang of it, I spent the last 4hrs reading about how I can make this possible but to no avail.

Comment: you can see the similar example in http://www.coderanch.com/t/439501/JSP/java/access-arraylist-jsp-javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you separate the data from the JavaScript, so you avoid scriplets and get a cleaner and more maintainable code.

First, create a servlet that generates a JSON file with the LandCoordinates, like this:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
for (LandCoordinates an : annex)
{
    sj.add("{\"posX\":" + an.getX() + ","
            + "\"posY\":\"" + an.getY() +"\"}");
}
response.getWriter().println(sj.toString());
```

Then create a static JavaScript that uses AJAX to get this JSON and do whatever you need. If you show the whole code I can help you.